# Do selected tests in Text Explorer window in Visual Studio 2015 run concurrently or sequentially?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

In Visual Studio 2015 for C#,

1. if I select several tests in the Test Explorer window, and right click to choose run the selected tests, will the selected tests  run simultaneously, or sequentially (i.e. one test starts automatically when the previous test finishes)?
2. If the tests  run simultaneously, is synchronization between different tests necessary?
3. If the tests  run simultaneously, how can I specify to run the selected tests sequentially instead of concurrently? This question is helpful when there are many tests which are to be run sequentially, to avoid some synchronization problem between them. There are too many of them to manually select one to run after another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article describing parallel test running in VS.NET 2015 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/

Some related summary from there:

1. Parallel test running is turned off by default. If you do nothing special - tests will be running one-by-one in any case.
2. Paralleling is done on assembly level - tests from the same assembly will be run sequentially no-matter-what
3. It's up to you to make your tests to support parallel run, in case you require shared data access / synchronization etc

So basically answering your question - just do nothing and tests will be running sequentially.

Comment: Thanks. I joined a project, and the people in the project said that the test methods in the project are run in parallel inside Visual Studio, and to run them sequentially I had to manually click them to run one by one. They don't know a way to automatically run the test methods sequentially.